I need to figure out calculation for a field in Tableau
I am working as a Data Analyst in a university and I am very new to this job. I have been told, If I don't get things working, there are some better people than me and they will hire them. I have been trying to calculate the number of students attending a set of events, and the number is varied from the excel sheet we feed into tableau and tableau dashboard itself. I didn't build the dashboard, and I am trying to troubleshoot the numbers.
So, Distinct Count of Students: 10,000; and total count of students is 30,000. But, if i do distinct count on total count of students it shows me 19320. But if I do a normal count on the distinct 10k students, it again shows 30,000.
I have no clue what's going on.
Help please.

Welcome to SE. Firstly, opening with 'help or I loose my job', is not something I would welcome. I am not responsible for your job - this is your responsibility. Lets stick to stats. Next, I would suggest isolating the error, if it is and error. You don't like something you see in 30k records. Can you isolate it to 10k?, what about 1k, or even 100. Then you might be able to see the problem with your eyes.

Also, why do you expect the distinct count and normal count to match? What are the differences between these?
